# Azure: Delete all *test.zip blobs from Azure Storage using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I would like to delete all files from an azure storage container where the filename includes test.zip

I am able to get all the files and export them to a file like this:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName ACCOUNTNAME `
                                   -StorageAccountKey ACCOUNTKEY

get-azurestorageblob -Container CONTAINERNAME                    `
                     -blob *test.zip                             `
                     -Context $context | Out-File c:\files\f.txt `
                     -width 500
```

What is the simplest way to delete all the results using the `remove-azurestorageblob` command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since blob storage only support individual blob deletes at this moment (i.e. it doesn't support batch deletes), your only option would be to read individual blobs from the output file and delete the blob one by one.

Based on your comments below, try the following:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "account name" -StorageAccountKey "account key"

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "containername" -blob *test.zip -Context $context | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

The script above will first list matching blobs and then delete them one by one.

Comment: Thanks Guarav!  Any chance your powershell skills extend to being able to help me write a script to read and delete using a foreach loop?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out :). Will update my answer once I find a solution (may not be ideal though considering my lack of expertise in PowerShell).

Comment: Do you need to save them to a file? Will it be OK if you delete the blobs after fetching the list through `get-azurestorageblob`?

Comment: It would be fine to delete without saving the list.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

I had this challenge when setting up **Azure storage accounts** for Static website hosting using **Powershell** in **Octopus Deploy**.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Using the [Az module for Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.7.0) I did the following:

```
# Define Variables
$RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME = my-resource-group
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = myapplication

# Get Storage Account Context
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -AccountName $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
$CONTEXT = $STORAGE_ACCOUNT.Context

# Remove all test.zip Files from the $web Storage Container
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container '$web' -Blob *test.zip -Context $CONTEXT | Remove-AzStorageBlob
```

OR

```
# Remove all Files and Folders from the $web Storage Container
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container '$web' -Blob * -Context $CONTEXT | Remove-AzStorageBlob
Write-Host 'Removed all files and folders from the $web Storage Container'
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: This is the simplest and clean approach

Answer (score 1):

With Azure CLI this got much easier as you can make use of `az storage blob delete-batch` for recursive deletion. For example for cleaning up the $web container of a static site one could use the following script:

```bash
# Define Variables
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'your-storage-account-name'

# Purge Container
az storage blob delete-batch -s '$web' --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --auth-mode login
```

Using the pattern parameter it is possible to delete only files matching a pattern e.g. the mentioned test.zip (`--pattern *test.zip`).

[Documentation of the Azure CLI blob delete-batch command](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_delete_batch)